# Handling alerts triggered by boolean condition; keep alertmanager from auto-resolving until manually cleared

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, prometheus-alertmanager

given the following `promql` with alertmanager integration:

what's a good way to alter this expression so that when a pod restart is indicated by this promql and an alert triggered (expected) that an alert isn't automatically resolved on the next check since on the next check it's likely a restart will no longer register (unless a pod is flapping or something). We want to be alerted so we can check it out so we want to manually resolve the alert:

`sum(rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[2m])*100) by (namespace,container) > 0`

A potential alertmanager rule would be the following, but we don't yet have an actual rule.

```
    - alert: Unexpected POD restart(s) occurring
      expr: sum(rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[2m])*100) by (namespace,container) > 0 
      for: 10s
      annotations:
        summary: POD restarts occurring
```

Comment: I'm not sure this can do done, but you can use [webhook config](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webhook_config) and use [alertmanager-webhook-logger](https://github.com/tomtom-international/alertmanager-webhook-logger) to log all the events. Just remember to set `send_resolved: true` in the webhook config so that is logs resolved events. I'm not sure if this is the solution but it certailny is a solution. You can also use some other [webhook receiver](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#alertmanager-webhook-receiver).

Answer (score 1):

An alert is raised when your query produces at least one metric and the alert is resolved when it no longer produces a metric.

```
sum by (...) (rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[2m])) > 0
```

means that it calculates the rate over the last two minutes. So if a restart occurs, the this expression will result in `0` after 2 minutes and your alert is resolved.

What you could do is simply increase the time interval:

```
sum by (...) (rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[1h])) > 0
```

so the alert stays on for an hour.

May be you dont want to check for every single restart, but if there are pods that restart within a specific time at least twice, so that might be the better expression:

```
sum by (...) (increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[24h])) > 2
```

meaning if a container restert at least two times within a day that might be a situation you want to have a look at.